# Twilio connection with android and web (Angular 6)

Tags: angular, typescript, twilio, twilio-video

I have implemented Twilio android SDK for video and Twilio-video-js for one angular application.
I have followed the documentation for implementation. 
when I place a call from the web to the android device it showing video on both ends. But when I make it vice-versa it doesn't show video on the web, but its connected since I get video from webcam to my android device.
After placing lots of consoles I get to know that its issue about tracks.

I used the following method for video in angular.

```html
connect(this.token, { name: this.room_name }).then(room => {
     console.log('room = ' + JSON.stringify(room));
     room.on('participantConnected', participants => {
       console.log(`A remote Participant connected: ${participants}`);
        participant.tracks.forEach(track => {
            console.log('tracks');
            document.getElementById('remote-media-div').appendChild(track.attach());
       });

       participants.on('trackAdded', track => {
         console.log('tracks2');
         document.getElementById('remote-media-div').appendChild(track.attach());
       });
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you still have the problem that videos aren't showing when calling Android -> web? What did you find when you logged the tracks?

Comment: Yeah, I found the solution for this. But there is a new issue, that I am not able to change the size of remote video tracks and local video tracks. @philnash

Comment: If you have a fresh question, I'd recommend asking a new question on SO.

Comment: @NikhilNyayadhish what was the solution?